# How to implement Pade Appromixation into State Space form

Tags: control-engineering

I have a State Space model and I need to create an Internal delay. Therefore I want to take a certain Padé approximation and convert it to ABCD matrices and extend my current model. However I do not no how to implement an Internal Delay to the State Space representation. I want to construct this by myself because my model is nonlinear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? How to convert the Padé approximation transfer function into a state space model or how to combine two state space models?

Comment: Well I have succeeded in both. Converting a Padé to SS model and used that model withing my State Space model. I do however have a problem. The timedelay of my Padé approximation is dependent on the order of my approximation.

For clarification. If my time delay is 10 seconds, and I use a Padé order 4, the simulation shows a time delay of around 5 seconds. If I use an order of 12, I get a time delay of 15 seconds. Order 8 brings my time delay close to the actual time delay. However I thought the order of Padé should not interfere with my time delay itself.

Comment: For clarification are you dealing with a continuous and not a discrete state space model? Also could you add to your question how you implemented it, so we can maybe spot where you might have made a mistake. Also Padé approximations only approximate delays well at low frequencies, so it might also be that the input to that approximation has a too high of a frequency content.

Comment: Im using a Continuous system.
For approximation I use Function = exp(-tau*s) where tau is my delay. The input could be considered as a step input.

Comment: I think has mainly to do with how I use the pade command in Matlab.
Because I define tau and s as a symbol first. Because I want the Padé approximation dependent on tau. I subs the tau later with the actual value.

This is the first piece of code

stepdelayx = exp(-tau*s);
pad = {};
for i = 1:12
padesym = pade(stepdelayx,'order',[i i]);

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently when I decompose my rational function into coefficients for the Denominator and Numerator. The coefficients were in opposite order. using the command fliplr in Matlab fixed this for me.

Comment: You used the num and den returned by pade to manually construct a state space model? Namely you can also just use ss(tf(num,den)) or ss(pade(exp(-tau*s)),N)) and Matlab will transform the transfer function into a state space model. I think this also has the advantage that the condition numbers of the matrices of the state space model are better behaved compared to using for example the controllable canonical form.

Comment: Yeah I create it manually to a TF and then TF2SS. However, trying your solution makes it a lot easier! thanks